# Using the definition of the derivative, prove that g(x) is not differentiable at x = 0.

Tags: derivatives

Using the definition of the derivative, you are required to prove that

$$g(x) = \sqrt{\frac{x^2(1+x)}{1-x}}, -1\le x \lt1$$

is NOT differentiable at x = 0. I know there exists a cusp at x = 0, but I need to use the definition of the derivative. Also I know that if g'(0) exists, then g(x) is differentiable at x = 0. Is it then okay to say that if g'(0) does not exist, then g(x) is not differentiable at x = 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course: if the limit of the Newton ratio doesn't exist, the function is not differentiable.

Hint:
$$
g(x)=|x|\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}}
$$
so you want to compute
$$
\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{g(x)-g(0)}{x}=
\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{|x|}{x}\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}}
$$
What about the limit for $x\to0^-$?